# Method under use jumps to next line instead of jumping the parameters

Tags: llvm-clang, clang-format

I'm having trouble configuring my clang-format file specially in this case. It might be a dummy question but I've tried several combinations and I could not manage to set it up.

**What I have:**

```
  bool res = MethodName(<ParameterList>);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(<ParameterList>);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(<ParameterList>);
  res      = res &&
        AdtVec_Equal(<ParameterList>); //same num of parameters, longer names
```

**What I want:**

```
  bool res = MethodName(<ParameterList>);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(<ParameterList>);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(<ParameterList>);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(<ParamA>, <ParamB>,
                                 <ParamC>);
```

I assume this is happening due to columnLimit value, but I do not want to set it longer. Any ideas?

My .clang-format file is the following:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM

AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  BeforeElse: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
ColumnLimit: 80
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth: 2
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 100
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: true
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
Standard: Auto
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I don't see any reasonable way to avoid this.

The exact behavior of `clang-format` will vary depending on the length of the parameters, and whether the function call is by itself or part of an expression. To see the differences, I created an example input file:

```
int f()
{
  bool res = MethodName(a, b, c, d);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooong, bLooooooong, cLoooooooong, dLoooooong);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooonger, bLooooooonger, cLoooooooonger, dLoooooonger);

  AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
  AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooooooong, bLooooooooooong, cLoooooooooooong, dLoooooooooong);
}
```

Your `.clang-format` settings then produce this:

```
int f()
{
  bool res = MethodName(a, b, c, d);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
  res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(a1, b1, c1, d1);
  res      = res &&
        AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooong, bLooooooong, cLoooooooong, dLoooooong);
  res = res && AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooonger, bLooooooonger, cLoooooooonger,
                            dLoooooonger);

  AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
  AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooooooong, bLooooooooooong, cLoooooooooooong,
               dLoooooooooong);
}
```

Notice that if the parameters are *really* long, you get the parameters the way you like them (`AdtVec_Equal` on the same line as `res`, and parameters break and get lined up under the first parameter). But there is a window where the parameters are long enough to prevent everything on one line, but short enough to allow the `AdtVec_Equal` call to fit on one line, and within this window, `clang-format` *really* wants to put the `AdtVec_Equal` call entirely on one line.

Possible workarounds:

1. You probably won't like it, but you can set `PenaltyExcessCharacter` to something very small, like `10`. That results in this output:

   ```
   int f()
   {
     bool res = MethodName(a, b, c, d);
     res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
     res      = res && AdtVec_Equal(a1, b1, c1, d1);
     res = res && AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooong, bLooooooong, cLoooooooong, dLoooooong);
     res = res && AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooonger, bLooooooonger, cLoooooooonger,
                               dLoooooonger);

     AdtVec_Equal(a, b, c, d);
     AdtVec_Equal(aLooooooooooooong, bLooooooooooong, cLoooooooooooong,
                  dLoooooooooong);
   }
   ```

   This manages to avoid having the `AdtVec_Equal` call on a separate line from `res`. But to achieve this, it mis-aligns the equal sign, and also extends the line beyond 80 characters. It will probably mess up other parts of your code as well.
2. You can manually format the code the way you like it, and then surround the code with `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on`.

---

I tested using `clang-format` 6.0.0, and also tested 10.0.0 using the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/). So this behavior has been there awhile and is probably not going to change without somebody creating a new style option and submitting a patch to implement it.